# Image cannot be resized in Itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itext, itext7

I am trying to resize a QR Code but it doesnt to be rescaling the image with the Image class... also I tried increasing the default image size with teh Qr library but it didnt work... what could I do to make it bigger?

```cs
 iTextSharp.text.Paragraph paragraph1 = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph();
            iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(model.Certificado.QrPath);
            image2.ScalePercent(150);


            iTextSharp.text.Chunk chunk = new iTextSharp.text.Chunk(image2, 0, 0);
            paragraph1.Add(chunk);
            ColumnText columnText2 = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
            columnText2.AddElement(paragraph1);
            anchoExtra = 700;
            colRightWidth = columnWidth + columnGap + anchoExtra;
            colTopOffset = 0.17f * pageSize.Height;
            colOffSetRight = pageSize.Width * 0.72f;//offset a la derecha
            colOffSetBottomPost = (0.35f * pageSize.Height) - 600;
            columnText2.SetSimpleColumn(colRightWidth, colTopOffset, colOffSetRight, colOffSetBottomPost);
            columnText2.Go();
```